# Golang: odd big Int behavior

Tags: go, biginteger, bigint

So I am new to Go and fairly inexperienced with programming in general so I hope I don't get downvoted again for asking stupid questions. 
I am working my way through the project euler problems and at problem 25 "1000-digit Fibonacci number" I encountered what seems to be strange behavior. The following is the code I wrote that resulted in this behavior.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    index := 2
    l := new(big.Int)
    pl := big.NewInt(1)
    i := big.NewInt(1)
    for {
        l = i
        i.Add(i, pl)
        pl = l
        index++
        if len(i.String()) == 1000 {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(i, "\nindex: ", index)
}
```

Naturally this did not generate the correct answer so in the process of determining why I discovered that I had inadvertently discovered a neat way to generate powers of 2. I made the following changes and this did generate the correct result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    index := 2
    l := new(big.Int)
    pl := big.NewInt(1)
    i := big.NewInt(1)
    for {
        l.Set(i)
        i.Add(i, pl)
        pl.Set(l)
        index++
        if len(i.String()) == 1000 {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(i, "\nindex: ", index)
}
```

My question is what is happening in the first example that causes each big Int variable to be set to the value of i and why this did not generate an error if this was not the correct way to assign a big Int var value? Is i = l, etc a legitimate big Int operation that is simply incorrect for this situation?

Answer (score 7):

The lines

```
l = i
```

and

```
pl = l
```

aren't doing what you think they are.

`l`, `pl`, and `i` are pointers, and assigning them to each other copies the pointer value, not the `big.Int` value.

After executing `l = i`, `l` is now the same *pointer* value as `i`, pointing to the same `big.Int`. When you use `l.Set(i)`, it sets `l`'s `big.Int` value to `i`'s `big.Int` value, but `l` and `i` still point to two separate values.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.